# Rename files with dynamic name in bash

Tags: bash, file, rename, mv

I am trying to rename all files which contains 'Name' with dynamic name.

So this file 'NameSomething' should look like this 'SearchSomething'. But script below just removes 'Name' from file name.

```
name='search'
Name='Search'

find ../../$name-module -name 'Name*' -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/Name/$Name}"' -- {} \;
```

Comment: Perhaps `$Name` doesn't get propagated through to the `exec`'d `bash` shell...  Maybe you can build the command string before your `find` and then `exec` it?

Comment: Your `$Name` is inside single quotes; it will not be expanded unless it is an environment variable (`export`'d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\You can escape quotes, no need for an export:

```
find ../../$name-module -name 'Name*' -type f -exec bash -c "mv \"\$1\" \"\${1/Name/$Name}\"" -- {} \;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working (in my case). I am running it in bash script and there is already $1 variable as a parameter, so it's trying to move string in this parameter instead of searched file name.

Answer (score 3):

You have to **export Name**, because otherwise the command find will not inherit the variable $Name into its environment. So:

```
name='search'
export Name='Search'

find ../../$name-module -name 'Name*' -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/Name/$Name}"' -- {} \;
```

Comment: @Tom: you should have accepted my answer. If find provides a full featured way to inherit and use variables, then why regress into \"' caligraphy :)

Comment: Because it is imho more clear solution than exporting variables you know :) I would accept both answers if I can. Anyone else thinks, that I should accept this answer instead?

Answer (score 1):

You might use find to find a list of the files you want to rename and pipe that to another program to do the renaming.

For example, you could do:

```
find ../../$name-module -print0 -name 'Name*' -type f | \
xargs -0 rename "s/Name/$Name/"
```

- No need for exporting (ugly + might affect other commands)
- Rename might get run only once (if all the found files fit on one command line) (with `-exec`, you're running two programs -- `bash` and `mv` -- per each file. That might be inefficient.

(You could get further performance increase with this approach by using Gnu `parallel` instead of `xargs`, if you're on a multicore computer)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Perl-based `rename` command:

```
Name=Search
rename "s/^Name/$Name/" *
```